# If statement using a count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a league table displayed below where all teams have played each other:

[image]

Based on their LeagueID, I want to determine that if the number of games played has reached MORE THAN its limit, then raise error saying 'season finished'.

I am a little loss on the IF statement and need a little assistance on how to determine this. I want to say in the example below that if more games than 22 is played, raise the error but I don't want to use a fixed value of 22 as I need to pretend that the league could be expanded at some point in the future with more teams.

How can this be done? At the moment the calculation counts all the teams per league, multiply by 2 to determine home and away and then minus 2 as each team doesn't play itself.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[League_Table_Insert]
    @LeagueName VARCHAR(30)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

    DECLARE @LeagueID INT
    DECLARE @TotalMatches INT

    SELECT 
    @LeagueID = LeagueID FROM dbo.League
    WHERE LeagueName = @LeagueName

    SELECT [Position], [TeamName], [Played], [Wins], [Loss], [Draws], [Points], [Goals_Scored], [Goals_Against], [Goal_Difference], [LeagueID]  
    FROM League_Table
    WHERE LeagueID = @LeagueID
    ORDER BY Points DESC, Goal_Difference DESC;

    --select [Position], [TeamName], [Played], [Wins], [Loss], [Draws], [Points], [Goals_Scored], [Goals_Against], [Goal_Difference], [LeagueID]   from League_Table

    SELECT @TotalMatches = SUM(COUNT(*) * 2 - 2) FROM dbo.League_Table WHERE LeagueID = @LeagueID

        IF  >= 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('season finished', 16, 1);
        RETURN;
    END
END
```

Comment: Why you want to raise it as error instead of showing it as alert. May not be relevant to your question but still

Comment: Why not pass the max value into the stored procedure, and set it in a config file or something?

Comment: I'm just using it to know the statement is working. I will be changing the error to an update statement later on. Instead of error it will be an update statement to set all the played, points, goal difference etc back to 0

Comment: @austinwernli Not thought of that, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF (SELECT MIN(Played) FROM dbo.League_Table WHERE LeagueID = @LeagueID) >= @TotalMatches
```

Assuming your total matches calculation is correct, it would make sense that the if statement looks for the lowest number of played matches for that league and checks against the total